# What is the equivalent to this from Jquery in prototype?

Tags: jquery, prototype

I just want to write smth like this in prototype:

```
$(".add_new_frontend_group").each(function(){

    x = $(this).find("a").find("span").text();

})
```

Now i am stuck at this point in prototype:

```
$$('.add_new_frontend_group').each( function (index) {

});
```

I also tried like this :

```
$$('.add_new_frontend_group').each( function (event) {
      x = event.findElement("a");

});
```

, but with no result

Comment: is that really complicated to that in prototype ? :P

Comment: If i really would know ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div  class="test">
    <a> hhh<p>sss</p> </a>
    <a> fff66<p>kkk</p></a>
</div>


$$(".test>a>p").each( function (val,i) {
alert(val.innerHTML);
});
```